# How to do multiple regexp tests in TCL?

Tags: regex, tcl

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my regexp statement? It doesn't match the "Operability: Degraded" line. I am trying to match anything that is not in operable state. I am new to TCL. Thanks!

Contents of $expect_out(buffer) it does the regexp on:

```
ID 20:
    Location: G1
    Presence: Equipped
    Overall Status: Operable
    Operability: Degraded
    Visibility: Yes
    Product Name: 16GB DDR3-1600-MHz RDIMM/PC3-12800/dual rank/1.35V
    PID: 
    VID: V01
    Vendor: 0x2C00
    Vendor Description: Micron Technology, Inc.
    Vendor Part Number: 
    Vendor Serial (SN): 
    HW Revision: 0
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Type: DDR3
    Capacity (MB): 16384
    Clock: 1600
    Latency: 0.600000
    Width: 64
```

Code:

```
proc check_errors { buffer cmd } {
        set count [ regexp -all -- { Activate-Status.*?!Ready|Overall.*Status.*?!Operable|Operability.*?!Operable|Controller.*Status.*?!Optimal|Errors.*?!0|Dr
opped.*?!0|Discarded.*?!0|Bad.*?!0|Suspect.*?!No|Thresholded.*?!0|Visibility.*?!Yes|Thermal.*Status.*?!OK|HA.*?!READY } $buffer ]

        if { [ set count ] != 0 } {
                puts "\tFAIL $cmd (Error Count: $count)"
        } else {
                puts "\tPASS $cmd"
        }
}
```

Output: (blade 6/5 has a known issue, it should fail the memory check)

```
Blade 6/5 checks...
        PASS show stats
        PASS show version
        PASS show adapter detail
        PASS show cpu detail
        PASS show memory detail
        PASS show inventory detail
```

Comment: What do you want to match with `Operability.*?!Operable`? `Operability` that is not followed with `Operable` on that line? Then, you actually need `Operability(?!.*Operable)`.

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm trying to do but that still doesnt work.

Comment: set count [ regexp -all -- { Activate-Status.*?!Ready|Overall.*Status.*?!Operable|Operability(?!.*Operable)|Controller.*Status.*?!Optimal|Errors.*?!0|Dropped.
*?!0|Discarded.*?!0|Bad.*?!0|Suspect.*?!No|Thresholded.*?!0|Visibility.*?!Yes|Thermal.*Status.*?!OK|HA.*?!READY } $buffer ]

Blade 6/5 checks...
        PASS show stats
        PASS show version
        PASS show adapter detail
        PASS show cpu detail
        PASS show memory detail
        PASS show inventory detail

Comment: It is crazy difficult to debug since your code does not compile. Please check [this demo](http://ideone.com/ASM47E) - is the regex working as expected?

Comment: It works now! Thanks for your help!

I had to add the ":" after the Operability in the regexp. So it's Operability:(?!.*Operable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***!term*** doesn't mean "anything but term" in regex. For that type of logic, you'll need a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) approach:

```
Activate-Status(?!.*Ready)|Overall.*Status(?!.*Operable)|Operability(?!.*Operable)|Controller.*Status(?!.*Optimal)|Errors(?!.*0)|Dropped(?!.*0)|Discarded(?!.*0)|Bad(?!.*0)|Suspect(?!.*No)|Thresholded(?!.*0)|Visibility.(?!.*yes)|Thermal.*Status(?!.*OK)|HA.*(?!.*READY)
```

[check it out here](https://regex101.com/r/jE4eA1/7)

note: I'd use case insensitivity to filter out both "No" and "no", and also, you must make sure your input is *not* treated as a single line, but multiple lines, so the .* wildcards don't race past the `\n` newlines and mess everything up.

Comment: It's looking for "!Operable"... as in anything BUT Operable. At least that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see your intent. Fixed to match your logic.

Comment: that works once I added the ":" part to the regexp. thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

@sweaver2112 has the right answer. I'd like to add maintainability into the mix:

- use the `-expanded` flag for additional non-meaningful whitespace
- use the `-line` so `.` does *not* match a newline (so "Ready" is on the same line as "Activate-Status")
- `-nocase` for case-insensitive matching (if that's important)

```
    set count [ regexp -all -expanded -line -- { 
        Activate-Status    (?!.*?Ready)    |
        Overall.*Status    (?!.*?Operable) |
        Operability        (?!.*?Operable) |
        Controller.*Status (?!.*?Optimal)  |
        Errors             (?!.*?0)        |
        Dropped            (?!.*?0)        |
        Discarded          (?!.*?0)        |
        Bad                (?!.*?0)        |
        Suspect            (?!.*?No)       |
        Thresholded        (?!.*?0)        |
        Visibility         (?!.*?Yes)      |
        Thermal.*Status    (?!.*?OK)       |
        HA                 (?!.*?READY)
    } $buffer ]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do multiple lookahead matching so it matches either "Operable" OR "Ok" like this?    Overall.*Status:(?!.*(Operable|Ok))

Comment: Yes. Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah, I must have other issues then. Wanted to make sure that was valid syntax. Thanks Glenn.